# I want to add text field in html dynamically using jquery or javascript to a particular button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

tis my code

```
<div class="rButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10" />10
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20" />20
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other" />other
</div>
```

I want, when someone choose "other" radio button, he shall be displayed with a text field where he can enter the value. This text field shall be to the right next to other.

Also I want that the box is restricted only for values in multiple of 10.

I m novice so please update the code and return me back.

i use jquery-1.4.2.js

Comment: u must be kidding me..looks like u r making us do your work ???? and ASAP....dude..FYI this question is most likely to get closed soon.. :):)

Comment: This sounds not a question, you can't expect us code for you

Comment: @user1999428 Have talents to get an IT boss once

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow as well as to coding :(

Comment: Two major conditions to get a boss once :)

Comment: ok then welcome to stackoverflow... go through the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am showing you in javascript.
First make your html file look like this

```
<div class="rButtons">
  <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10" onclick="uncheck();" />10
  <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20"  onclick="uncheck();" />20
  <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other" onclick="check(this);"/>other
  <input type="text" id="other_field" name="other_field" onblur="checktext(this);"/>
</div>
```

In the second step write this css code to initially set the text field invisible.

```
<style type="text/css">
#other_field
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Finally use this javascript code to validate the user's behaviour

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uncheck()
     {
       document.getElementById('other_field').style.visibility = "hidden";
     }
    function check(inputField)
    {
        if(inputField.checked)
        {
            document.getElementById('other_field').style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
    function checktext(inputField)
    {
        if(isNaN(inputField.value))
        {
            alert('only numbers are allowed..');
            return false;
        }
        else if( (inputField.value % 10 ) != 0)
        {
            alert('only multiples of 10..');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    </script>
```

The first function detects if user clicked the "other" radio button and displays the hidden
text filed..

The second function validates the input field as per your requirements...

Comment: dude you rocks... I have not checked though.. :) thanks a lot.. i ll return with any question in my mind..

Comment: but a lil problem.. on selecting another radio button the text box does not disappers.. it stays there :(

Comment: ok..i will just change the code a little...what i am going to do .. is not great..but it will serve your purpose...i have edited the code...above...just see..if it works...!!!

Comment: @Narendra.. why you mentioned it as not great?? Is there any specific reason for that??

Comment: also can we meet at anyplace other than this platform? like s-k-.y-p-.e?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript with jquery you do like that. And try to work out on your end first.

```
  var item = $('input[name=numbers]:checked').val();
    if(item == 'other'){
    //Show your textbox
    }
```

Comment: thans murtaza.. let me try then i come back to you :)

Comment: but where do i have to add this text u mentioned above??

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="rButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10" />10
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20" />20
    <input type="radio"  name="numbers" value="other" /><span class="text-other">other</span>
    <input class="user-input" style="display: none"></input>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr('value') == 'other') {
        $('.text-other').hide();
        $('.user-input').show();
    } else {
        $('.text-other').show();
        $('.user-input').hide();
    }
});
```